# How do I write a question that sounds like a statement?

Tags: punctuation, phonetics

Forgive me if the title is unclear.

I am trying to understand how to write two questions, but with the latter question *sounding* like a statement.

Examples:

> a) Should I go with option A, or option B?
>
> b) Do you want to stay here? Or do you want to go home.
>
> c) Can I visit today; or do I have to wait until tomorrow?

The former part of all the examples sound as though they are questions, and the latter part of the examples sound as though they are statements. (It's kind of hard to explain without being able to vocalize it - say **example B** out loud to see what I mean).

I want to be able to write a sentence that sounds like **example B** if said aloud, but that is also grammatically correct.

Comment: How do you write a question that sounds like a statement? Use a rhetorical question and answer it immediately.

Comment: "I'd like you to please tell me whether you'd like to go home or stay here."

Comment: When you ask something like: "Do you want to go home? Or do you want to stay here?" .. You don't ask both of them as questions if you ask them aloud, you ask the first one as a question, and the second one as a statement (tone of voice/phonetics)

Comment: Not sure where you learned that, but each of your examples contain two questions, whether written or spoken. Example b) needs a second question mark, as it is two sentences.  But a) and c), with their comma and semicolon respectively, are punctuated correctly as single sentences.